# Group products when showing recently sold items using sales/order_item

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order

I can show the most recently sold items and sort them based on `created_at` using this:

```
$itemsCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(5);

/*$itemsCollection->getSelect()->group('product_id');*/

foreach($itemsCollection as $item) {
    echo $item->getName() . ' - ' . $item->getData('created_at') . '</br>';
}
```

This will show as:

```
Product_A - 2016-07-22 09:02:59
Product_B - 2016-07-22 07:03:44
Product_A - 2016-07-22 01:13:09
Product_C - 2016-07-21 23:13:00
Product_D - 2016-07-21 22:16:32
```

So there is two Product_A and 3 with a date 2016-07-22 Which is exactly how it should be but when I try and group the items, I do not see any item/order from 2016-07-22.

To group, I am using `$itemsCollection->getSelect()->group('product_id');`

This will show as:

```
Product_E - 2016-07-21 21:13:00
Product_A - 2016-07-21 16:07:08
Product_F - 2016-07-21 05:26:06
Product_G - 2016-07-20 08:03:11
Product_H - 2016-07-18 10:36:29
```

What is happening?

Is there a way around this? I want to display recently sold items but I do not want duplicates.

Comment: Does anyone use this site anymore?

Comment: if you select non-grouped columns in a query with `group by`, those are non-deterministic. So you will get one arbitrary result per product. To me it is not qutite clear, what result you expect instead. Can you give an example for the desired result as well?